# Registration and Log In system

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am brand new to PHP, HTML5, and CSS. I am in the process of building my website. [This](http://www.tickerfinder.com) is the address. When I click <kbd>START FREE TRIAL</kbd> it is meant to register the user on a database and give them access to other pages on the site. From then on they log in. The issue being, that when <kbd>START FREE TRIAL</kbd> is clicked, the user is able to access the other pages, but I am unable to see the registration in the database fields/columns via phpMyAdmin in Cpanel. As far as I understand the `server.php` (below) is connecting to the database server, and that is why access is being granted to the other pages.

When trying to log in, an error dialogue appears within the frame. Should the code below work? Or is there something I have done wrong? Hopefully I have posted my `server.php` correctly.

```
<?php 
session_start();

// variable declaration
$fname = "";
$lname = "";
$username = "";
$email    = "";
$password = "";
$errors = array(); 
$_SESSION['success'] = "";

$dbh = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "usrname", "password")
or die ('I cannot connect to the database.');
mysqli_select_db ("db_name");




// REGISTER USER
if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
    // receive all input values from the form
    $fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh, $_POST['fname']);
    $lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh, $_POST['lname']);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh, $_POST['username']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh, $_POST['email']);
    $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh, $_POST['password_1']);
    $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh, $_POST['password_2']);

    // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled
    if (empty($fname)) { array_push($errors, "First Name is required"); }
    if (empty($lname)) { array_push($errors, "Last Name is required"); }
    if (empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username is required"); }
    if (empty($email)) { array_push($errors, "Email is required"); }
    if (empty($password_1)) { array_push($errors, "Password is required"); }

    if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
        array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");
    }

    // register user if there are no errors in the form
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password_1);//encrypt the password before saving in the database
        $query = "INSERT INTO users (fname, lname, username, email, password) 
                  VALUES('$fname','$lname', '$username', '$email', '$password')";
        mysqli_query($dbh, $query);

        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
        header('location: Continue.php');
    }

}

// ... 

// LOGIN USER
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh, $_POST['username']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbh, $_POST['password']);

    if (empty($username)) {
        array_push($errors, "Username is required");
    }
    if (empty($password)) {
        array_push($errors, "Password is required");
    }

    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        $password = md5($password);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
        $results = mysqli_query($dbh, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
            header('location: Continue.php'); 
        }else {
            array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like your sql query is failing. Try killing your script just after the SQL and see what errors are being thrown out with `mysqli_error($dbh)`

Comment: WillParky93 thanks for that. Will give that a go.

Comment: `mysqli_select_db ("db_name");` that failed you. Read the manual on that and you will see the syntax for it.

Comment: Fred -ii- 19 thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to and WillParky93 and Fred -ii who pointed me in the right direction. This has been solved by changing this

```
$dbh = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "usrname", "password")
or die ('I cannot connect to the database.');
mysqli_select_db ("db_name");
```

to

```
$dbh = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "usrname", "password")
or die ('I cannot connect to the database.');
mysqli_select_db ($dbh, "db_name");
```